# performance difference between location.href and window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I have been read location.href is faster than window.location.href. But internally location.href is being read as window.location.href right? So how it would increase the significant performance?

Comment: Do you really have performance problem on this topic ? I don't think so. I you really think you have, use Chrome's profiler to check.

Comment: I think u could have read High performance javascript book before downvoting it

Comment: I wasn't the one downloading. But really, look for your real performance problems before losing your time on (implementation dependant) details.

Comment: @dystroy: I don't read the question that way. I read it as: People say this would be faster, but *why* would it be faster? E.g., wanting to understand the underlying mechanism, rather than actually being worried about the performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have been read location.href is faster than window.location.href.

It might be ***infinitessimally*** faster, but nothing you'd notice in real life. Here's why:

Here's what the engine does (in theory) when it sees `location.href`:

- Looks up `location` in the current scope; if not found, goes to the containing scope and so on, eventually reaching global scope.
- At global scope, `location` is found as a property of the global object.
- Then it looks up the `href` property on the `location` object.

Here's what the engine does (in theory) when it sees `window.location.href`:

- Looks up `window` in the current scope; if not found, goes to the containing scope and so on, eventually reaching global scope.
- At global scope, `window` is found as a property of the global object; it's a property the global object uses to refer to *itself*.
- Then it looks up the `location` property on that object.
- Then it looks up the `href` property on the `location` object.

So `window.location.href` requires one more property lookup than `location.href` does — barring any optimizations the JavaScript engine might be able to apply. But JavaScript performance is *incredibly* variable from engine to engine; your mileage may vary. [Here's a benchmark](http://jsperf.com/window-vs-direct-access) that [FB55 put together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10461710/157247) showing that the theory above is borne out by experimental results; `location.href` is indeed faster. In that particular test.

[image: Gratuitous benchmark screenshot]

(Blue = `location.href`, red = `window.location.href`; longer lines = faster performance.)

More to the point: **Does it really matter? Not in the real world, no.** You'd have to be doing this millions of times for there to be any human-perceptible difference. But that's the explanation for why you'll see people saying this about globals like `location` (or any other global, built-in or added by your own code).

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: (My answer, you mean.) Actually, I did, because you overwrote my rather more useful edit. If I'd wanted to say *teeny tiny* etc., I'd've done so. :-)

Answer (score 1):

document.location is deprecated in favor of window.location, which can be accessed by just location, since it's a global object.

The location object has multiple properties and methods. If you try to use it as a string then it acts like location.href. To be on the safe side it's best to always use location.href

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts on this:

- In browsers, `window` is the global object, so all properties assigned to it can be accessed without referencing it. In both cases, the variables need to be searched in every surrounding scope (read: even the window object needs to be searched).
- To avoid expensive searching, most modern browsers implemented a technique called "Inline Caching" (IC). Simplified, that means you're always pointing to the right object.

Anyway, I created a [simple benchmark](http://jsperf.com/window-vs-direct-access). Apparently, the direct access is faster (at least in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

In a first look they do the same thing, they could have different behaviour in case you are using frames.

In that case they could return different values, probably having some performance difference according to your frame-nesting complexity, but ignoring the frame stuff, they sould do the same thing in the same time.

Please specify where did you read about this.

HTH